# Should I say "I had a fever" or "I suffered from a fever" or "I experienced a fever"

Tags: word-usage, phrasal-verbs

If I want to tell my teacher the reason for my absence, which one of these is preferable? I feel uncomfortable when I am sick and down with fever.

> I had a fever.
>
> I suffered from a fever.
>
> I experienced a fever.

Comment: I had a fever. Simple & to the point. The others are grammatically correct, but too awkward.

Comment: That's one long fever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I had a fever.

is fine and a natural expression.

BYW, in your description, I would use *forehead* not *fronthead*, and *temperature go down* rather than *heat changed less*. Also I am guessing you did not lay in your bed *for some years*.

But still a good description and completely understandable.

Answer (score 3):

Being a doctor, I often hear this as a symptom.

> I had a fever

However, from my *medical brain*, another phrase comes:

> I was [***running*** a fever](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fever).

As a special case, you also *run* a fever/temperature. This means you had fever.

Answer (score 0):

If you felt pain, then you suffered.
BUT the fever should not make you feel pain.
I guessed it was other illness causing a set of common symptoms for some reason.
You could tell your teachers that you had a fever.